# python-crontab Как удалить определенное задание

Tags: python, python-3.x, crontab

Всем привет, я создаю задания с помощью python скрипта, вот так:

```
from crontab import CronTab
        
cron = CronTab('name')
job = cron.new(command=f'python3 /home/name/PycharmProjects/vkbot/posting_script.py {token} {idg} "{text}"')
job.minute.every(interval)
cron.write()
```

И все работает отлично, но мне нужно как-то удалить одно задание из списка.

К примеру создал я 3 задания, а по запросу пользователя мне нужно удалить 2-е.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне определить какое именно мне нужно удалить задание(по идентификатору может какому-то) и как его удалить c помощью питон скрипта?